# Change name of exported pdf in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, pdfmake

I am using pdfmake.js for exporting ui-grid data as a pdf file. However, I am not able to find any option to change the name of the exported file dynamically. Everytime the file is downloaded with same name but I want to change its name on the basis of some selections in ui-grid.

Here is the code I use

```
$scope.gridName = { 
    columnDefs: [ //column definations ],
    exporterCsvFilename: 'Details.csv', 
    exporterPdfDefaultStyle://some value
    exporterPdfTableStyle://some value
    // other proprties
};
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the file?

Comment: $scope.gridName = { 
    columnDefs: [   //column definations  ],
    exporterCsvFilename: 'Details',
    exporterPdfDefaultStyle://value
    exporterPdfTableStyle://value
    //other proprties
    };

Comment: You didn't include the code that makes the call to create the pdf, uness I'm missing it. Add the code to your question :)

Comment: Pdf is generated automatically i don't need to call it explicitly,pdfmake.js integration with ui-grid gives an option in grid-menu to export data as pdf.
However i know the option which disables pdf export i.e. exporterMenuPdf: false,

Comment: Thank you, didn't know there were an integration between the two. Will look into it.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @davids
no updates i guess
i finally solved the problem by giving the file name as the header to the generated pdf like
exporterPdfHeader: { text: "My Header", style: 'headerStyle' },